# How to typeset an array using package readarray

Tags: readarray

Thanks in advance for any attention you give to this question!
I'm trying to read an array from an external file, print some elements of it, and then typeset the array in my document. I'm able to read the array, and to display elements of it, but I can't seem to typeset the array after.  Please see the code below (which comes directly from the package.)  The error I'm getting is "undefined control sequence \typesetarray".  The file "SN-summary.csv" has the following data in a .csv file.

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{readarray}
\readarraysepchar{,}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\readdef{SN-summary.csv}\SNdata
\readarray\SNdata\SNarray[3,\ncols]

\SNarray[3,2] \par

\typesetarray\SNarray

\end{document}
```

Comment: I get no error on an up-to-date TeX distribution. On the other hand, I get the error if I try to compile with TeX Live 2020.

Comment: Hmmmm, do you think I have an install problem?  I reinstalled Latex and TexLive, and haven't seen a change in the file output.  Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: It's Mac OS Ventura.  This is their most recent operating platform.

Comment: Install the most recent MacTeX https://tug.org/mactex

Comment: Wow!  That worked perfectly.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

The code was fine, it was the Mac OS that needed a change.  I had recently installed Mac OS Ventura.  In order to fix the problem, I reinstalled MacTex from [tug.org/mactex].

Comment: MacTeX is update yearly, together with TeX Live. You should also run, from time to time, TeX Live Utility in order to get package updates.